# How to iterate a map of type <string,long>?

Tags: c++, maps, operator-keyword

```
map<string,long>::iterator iter; iter=phonebook.begin();
    while (iter != phonebook.end()){
        if(name==(*itr).first){
            cout<<(*itr).first<<"="<<(*itr).second<<endl;
            c=1;
            break;
        }
```

This code throws this error:

```sh
[Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, long int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, long int> >}'
                                                and 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator      {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> >}')
```

Comment: Please share your full code as it is difficult to understand what c,itr and name are

Comment: It kind of looks like the type of your map is actually a `map<string, int>`

Answer (score 0):

When you were initializing your variables, you forgot to set the type for "iter". So, it should've been

```
map<string, long>::iterator iter = phonebook.begin();
```

However, initializing iterator this way is time consuming. Therefore, by current standards, it is better to implement "auto" keyword

```
auto iter = phonebook.begin();
```

"auto" will set the type for the given variable based on the type of the right side of the expression.
To make it even better, you could use brace-initialization

```
auto iter { phonebook.begin() };
```

Comment: "*When you were initializing your variables, you forgot to set the type for "iter"*" - no, they didn't. `map<string,long>::iterator iter; iter=phonebook.begin();` is perfectly valid as separate statements. The real problem is that `map<string,long>` is the wrong container type to begin with. Using `auto` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error message that your `phonebook` is not declared as `map<string,long>` but is actually declared as `map<string,int>` instead, so you need to change the declaration of the iterator accordingly:

```cpp
map<string,int>::iterator iter = phonebook.begin();
while (iter != phonebook.end()) {
    if (name == (*itr).first) {
        cout << (*itr).first << "=" << (*itr).second << endl;
        c = 1;
        break;
    }
```

`long` and `int` are different types, thus `map<string,long>`and `map<string,int>` are different container types. You can't mix iterators from different container types.

A better solution is to use `auto` instead to let the compiler deduce the type of iterator to use:

```cpp
auto iter = phonebook.begin();
while (iter != phonebook.end()) {
    if (name == itr->first) {
        cout << itr->first << "=" << itr->second << endl;
        c = 1;
        break;
    }
```

Which can then be simplified further by using a [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop instead:

```cpp
for(const auto &elem : phonebook()) {
    if (name == elem.first) {
        cout << elem.first << "=" << elem.second << endl;
        c = 1;
        break;
    }
```

However, your loop is `break`'ing on the first matching element, so you should consider using the standard [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm instead of a loop, eg:

```cpp
auto iter = std::find_if(phonebook.begin(), phonebook.end(),
    [&](const auto &elem){ return name == elem.first; }
);
if (iter != phonebook.end()) {
    cout << iter->first << "=" << iter->second << endl;
    c = 1;
}
```